# Massive ultracapacitor banks, why don't they work? (400V 3.38F)

Tags: capacitor

This might be a stupid question, and I know that for high energy, quick discharge applications (like a railgun for example) supercapacitors don't really work, but why?

If I were to take hundreds of ultracapacitors (let's say they are 2.7V 500F individually), and then hook them up in series to get a 400V 3.378F capacitor bank, shouldn't that work better than a 400V 63300µF aluminum electrolytic capacitor bank?

Comment: Can you cite why you think supercaps aren't useful here?  That isn't my recollection at all.

Comment: If you put 100 capacitors in series the total capacitance is 100 times smaller... You need 10,000 of them to get the same capacitance at 100x voltage

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of reasons.

First is energy, E = 0.5*C*V^2 so capacitance is not as important as voltage in this regard.

Coil guns need an incredibly quick pulse of current to work effectively. Think of this in terms of a time constant, RC. If you have a larger capacitance, the bank will discharge slower and the field will be present longer which (if the projectile passes the coil) will actually slow it down.

Also, think of the ESR of a capacitor. If you have hundreds of caps in series, that ESR will be through the roof compared to a bunch in parallel. This will also increase your time constant.

Super caps are nice, don't get me wrong, they just have their own niche uses.

Answer (score 3):

Let's do some math.

[500F 2.7V supercap](https://nz.mouser.com/datasheet/2/40/AVX-SCC-LE-1222679.pdf):- ESR = 1mΩ.

x 148 in series = 3.38F @ 400V, and 1mΩ x 148 = **148mΩ**

[4700uF 400V electrolytic capacitor](https://nz.mouser.com/datasheet/2/212/KEM_A4034_PEH200-1101128.pdf):- ESR = 18mΩ.

x 13 in parallel = 61100uF @ 400V, and 18mΩ / 13 = **1.4mΩ**

The 13 capacitor Al electrolytic bank has **105 times lower ESR** than the 148 capacitor supercap bank.

Comment: Of course you are correct, but it may be helpful to explain to OP *why* low ESR is advantageous here.

Comment: @MIL-SPEC other people have answered that question (which the OP hopefully already knows. Do we really have to assume they are all total newbies who know _nothing_ about electronics?)

Answer (score 1):

> This might be a stupid question, and I know that for high energy,
>   quick discharge applications (like a railgun for example)
>   supercapacitors don't really work, but why?

The difference in capacitors is the ESR (Equivalent Series Resistance), you can look up this value in most capacitor datasheets. The series resistance is from the total physical resistance of the terminals and electrolyte, the resistance creates loss and a voltage drop internal to the capacitor.

Super\ultra capactors have very low ESR in the mΩ and very high capacitance. Electrolytic capacitors have higher ESR in the 10mΩ to 100mΩ range. So even if you were to create a bank of regular electrolytic capacitors, it would have a large internal resistance and this would make it less useful. To make an equivalent bank from regular capactors would take much more volume and weight.

Also this:

> A supercapacitor is also known as ultracapacitor or double-layer
>   capacitor. A supercapacitor tends to differ from an ordinary capacitor
>   due to its very high capacitance
>   Source: https://www.spscap.com/difference-capacitor-supercapacitor.html

Comment: Doesn't this say that super caps are *better* for railguns than electrolytics?

Comment: As far as I'm aware it's super capacitors that are making modern rail gun applications possible

Comment: That's what I thought, too.  In 1987, I think, I saw a presentation by Hodding Carter about tech coming out of the Strategic Defense Initiative (Star Wars!), which was based largely on the concept of orbiting rail guns.  A big part of the tech was better dielectrics.

Comment: Can you post a source Voltage Spike? (if you had something specific in mind). My answer was mostly anecdotal and I'd hate to be providing incorrect info (especially when it comes to coil guns). Although maybe it was for rail guns, which are not the same as coil guns?

Comment: @ScottSeidman I totally agree, and better dielectrics also increase the storage of the capacitor (and also increasing surface area of the cathode and anode with novel materials). But at the same time you need low ESR so when you put them in series you can still run large currents through them without loss. For this you need large terminals and properly sized anodes/cathodes, a large surface area and a good dielectric. You could potentially build a rail gun with electrolytes, but you might not be able to get the current out fast enough because of the ESR (and ESL).

Comment: I think it would be worth noting that while supercaps may have lower ESR / ESL than equivalent electrolytic caps, they still have much higher ESR / ESL than most other capacitor technologies e.g. MLCC and film caps.